# Append sensor data to a file, column specific

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a while loop reading in sensor measurements continuously. I would like to write the measured sensor values to a file.

```
while True:
    f = open(r'C:\Users\me\Documents\data.txt', 'a') #open a data file to append to

    res = snsrcntrl.getmeasur(controller.MeasureType.87) #87 is sensor 1
    date_1 = (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res.timestamp)) #get current date and time
    measure_1 = res.numericValue

#res is called again to get a new measurement

    res = snsrcntrl.getmeasur(controller.MeasureType.57) #57 is sensor 2
    date_2 = (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(res.timestamp))
    measure_2 = res.numericValue

    data = date_1 + ',' + "{0:.3f}".format(measure_1) + ',' + date_2 + ',' + "{0:.3f}".format(measure_2) + '\n'
    f.write(data)
```

This method will work, but I am looking for a more elegant way. If I could specify the column I write the data to that would be great (f.append(date_2[3]), something along those lines.

Things will get very long when I want to write 10 dates and 10 measurements.

Comment: what is returned from `snsrcntrl.getmeasur()` ? Is it a dictionary.  You could consider using pandas with `json_normalize()`

Comment: It returns a string, i.e., 1093.2321